# We haven't imported your Public Link because it is no longer possible to make it private?

Tags: support, developer-story

Trying out the new Developer Story feature, imported my crumbling old CV, and got this message:

[image: We haven't imported your Public Link because it is no longer possible to make it private.]

I don't exactly understand what this means; am I losing my vanity URL? Do vanity URLs no longer exist after the transition to Dev Story? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 8):

This message will no longer exist (because it won't be necessary anymore) after [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320915/115866) is implemented, which brings back the possibility to reserve a vanity URL without making the page public yet.

See the [previous version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/320082/2) of this answer for an explanation of the original behavior.

Comment: What does this mean to me, as someone moving to the new Story system? I keep the old careers/cv link but /story/ is up for grabs by whoever signs up first? Or is there a window of time during which my old name still reserved? (I don't actually want to test this, since grabbing someone else's name For Science would be pretty tragic if they actually wanted it)

Comment: `/cv/xyz` and `/story/xyz` always come together, you can't have one without the other. We don't currently have plans of a "window of time" as you suggest, but the idea isn't bad. Finally, feel free to test (for science) during the beta. Existing CV data trumps beta URLs, so if (during the beta) you pick a URL that already belongs to somebody's CV, then after the beta, they'll get it back. (Not sure what exactly you'd test though).

Comment: So I did a bit of testing. Right now, if I try to take someone else's slug on Careers, I'm blocked (even if their slug is private). During the private beta, it appears I can grab anyone's slug for a new /story/ URL as long as they haven't made it public yet - if I beat them to it, they get assigned a new slug (slug+number) when they import, and told they'll get their old one back when the beta ends. But if I'm interpreting this correctly, I'll still be able to snipe anyone's *private* slug once the beta has ended, and they'll have no recourse but to go public under a new one. Yes?

Comment: Yep, that sounds about right. But you don't *know* their slug because it doesn't work in the first place. (By the way, this starts to sound more like a feature request than a support discussion, so if you'd like to change the current behavior maybe this should be moved to a new question.)

Comment: I'm writing up a feature-request, but I wanted to make sure I understood how this actually worked before I proposed changing it. ;-)

Comment: This behavior should not be the case - since the links that are private on Careers now may have been used *in the past*. This would mean changing links (that are personal identity) to go to a different person. IMO, this is something we should avoid as best we can.

Comment: Please see follow-up feature-request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320090/reserve-careers-cv-slugs-in-developer-story-if-theres-a-chance-theyve-ever-bee